# Problemas con Sumas JS

Tags: javascript, firebase

El problema que me surge de seguro es muy simple, lo que presento en el código es algo realizado con `Firebase` que me devuelve todos los datos de mi `DB` y me los coloca en una tabla.

Al final en `"Total"` le asigno el primer "monto" para que luego le sume el próximo y lo ingrese a `"cellTotal"`, pero en lugar de sumar me lo concatena como si todo monto fuera un `string`, siendo que desde la `DB` me llega como entero y a `"Total"` lo inicializo como un `int`.

Les agradeceria la ayuda.

**Edito:**

En su momento me concatenaba a causa de que colocaba `cellTotal += nuevoServicio.monto`, pero de la siguiente manera solo me muestra el ultimo objeto de la base `total = total + nuevoServicio.monto;  cellTotal.innerText = total;` si haber sumado lo pedido.

```
//Mantengo actualizada la tabla de servicios
dbSer.on('child_added', snap => {
var nuevoServicio = snap.val();

let cellTotal= document.querySelector('#totalImpuesto');
let total = 0;
let tb = document.querySelector('#tb-body');

let tr = document.createElement('tr');
let td1 = document.createElement('td');
let td2 = document.createElement('td');

let text1 = document.createTextNode(nuevoServicio.servicio);
let text2 = document.createTextNode(nuevoServicio.monto);

td1.appendChild(text1);
td2.appendChild(text2);

tr.appendChild(td1);
tr.appendChild(td2)

tb.appendChild(tr);

total = total + nuevoServicio.monto;

cellTotal.innerText = total;
})
```

El resultado de un `console.log(JSON.stringify(nuevoServicio))` me devuelve:

```
{"monto":3000,"servicio":"Casa"}
{"monto":200,"servicio":"Gas"}
{"monto":350,"servicio":"Luz"}
```

El cual claramente es un INT.

Y al agregar:

`total = total + parseInt(nuevoServicio.monto, 10);
    cellTotal.innerText = total`

Me devuelve 350 que es el ultimo objeto de la base.

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el resultado de hacer `console.log(JSON.stringify(nuevoServicio))`? Me da a sensación que `nuevoServicio.monto` viene como `string` y no como `int`

Comment: Qué te devuelve tu variable nuevoServicio.monto?

Comment: Disculpen la demora, andaba afuera. 

Ahi edite la pregunta, pero como les digo, de `firebase` por consola me llega como `int`.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Duda en JavasScript Suma o Concatenación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174219/duda-en-javasscript-suma-o-concatenaci%c3%b3n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La única razón por la que los valores serían concatenados (en lugar de ser sumados) es porque `nuevoServicio.monto` tiene que ser un `string`.

### Solución:

Podrías usar [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) (*sin decimales*) o [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseFloat) (*con decimales*)

### Ejemplo:

```
total = total + parseInt(nuevoServicio.monto, 10);
```

---

### Update

La razón  por la que obtienes sólo el ultimo valor es porque cada vez que se ejecuta el evento `child_added`, la variable `total` es inicializada a `0`.

### Solución:

Deberías inicializar la variable `total` fuera de la función.

### Ejemplo:

```
let total = 0;
dbSer.on('child_added', snap => {
  var nuevoServicio = snap.val();

  let cellTotal= document.querySelector('#totalImpuesto');
  //... resto del código
```

Comment: Es lo que yo pense, que podia llegar de la base como un string, pero previo a consultar en Stack verifique que me llegara como entero y asi lo hace.

La verdad es que no logro ver el porque me lo concatena, salvando este caso que te devuelve el ultimo elemento del array.

Comment: *Ultimo objeto de la base*  no del array. perdon.

Comment: @Alfacoy, he actualizado mi respuesta

Comment: Le diste al blanco!... Lo di por perdido por hoy y me habia puesto a avanzar con otra parte del codigo. Muchisimas gracias Marcos.