# ¿Por qué una variable es concatenada a otra en lugar de ser sumada, en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo un módulo de venta, a través de Javascript para colocar los valores en vista y también algunas funciones.

El error se presenta cuando quiero hacer un cálculo para saber el iva del producto y luego sumar el iva y el precio... El problema es que en lugar de sumarlo me lo reconoce como si lo estuviera concatenando. El código de JS es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#bt_add").click(function(){
        agregar();
  });
});
   var cont=0;
   total = 0;
   subtotal=[];

  $("#guardar").hide();
  $("#pidConcepto").change(mostrarValores);

  function mostrarValores() {
    datosArticulo=document.getElementById('pidConcepto').value.split("_");
    $('#pprecio').val(datosArticulo[1]);
    $('#pimpuesto').val(datosArticulo[2]);
  }

  function agregar() {

        datosArticulo=document.getElementById('pidConcepto').value.split('_');
        
        idConceptosPagos=datosArticulo[0];
        consepto=$("#pidConcepto option:selected").text();
        precio=$("#pprecio").val();
        impuesto=$("#pimpuesto").val();
        cantidad=$("#pcantidad").val();

        if(consepto!=" " &&  precio!=" " && impuesto!=" " && cantidad!= " ")
        {


               iva = precio * 16 / 100;
              subtotal[cont] = precio+iva;
              total=total+subtotal[cont];

              var fila ='<tr class="selected" id="fila' + cont +'" ><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><input type="hidden" name="idConceptosPagos[]" value="'+idConceptosPagos+'">'+consepto+'</td><td><input type="text" name="precio[]" readonly="readonly" value="'+precio+'"></td><td><input type="text" name="cantidad[]" readonly="readonly" value="'+cantidad+'"></td><td type="text" name=impuesto[] readonly>'+impuesto+'</td><td>'+ subtotal[cont]+'</td></tr>';
              
              cont++;
              limpiar();
              $("#total").html("$/. " + total);
              evaluar();
              $("#detalles").append(fila);
              
        }else {

             
              alert("Error al ingresar el detalle de la venta, revise los datos del articulo");
              
        }
  }

function limpiar() {
  $("#pimpuesto").val("");
  $("#pprecio").val("");

}

 function evaluar(){

  if (total>0) {
        $("#guardar").show();
  }
  else {
       $("#guardar").hide();  
  }
}    
 function eliminar(index) {
 
 total=total-subtotal[index];
 $("#total").html("$/. " + total);

 $("#fila" + index).remove();
 evaluar();
 }
```

y el html es:

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  

  {!!Form::open(array('url'=>'utp/venta/concepto','method'=>'POST','autocomplete'=>'off'))!!}
        {{Form::token()}}
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="idAlumno">Alumno</label>
              <select name="idAlumno" id="idAlumno" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                                @foreach($alumnos as $alum) 
                                <option value="{{$alum->idAlumno}}">{{$alum->nombre}}</option> 
                                @endforeach             
                          </select>
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="idCiclo">Ciclos</label>
              <select name="idCiclo" id="idCiclo" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
                                @foreach($ciclos as $ciclo) 
                                <option value="{{$ciclo->idCiclo}}">{{$ciclo->codigoCorto}}</option> 
                                @endforeach             
                          </select>
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="clave">Clave</label>
              <input  class="form-control" required type="text" value="{{old('clave')}}" name="clave" id="pclave" placeholder="Clave del pago ">
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="anio">Año</label>
              <input type="text" name="anio" id="anio" class="form-control" value="{{old('anio')}}" placeholder="Año....">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="mes">Mes</label>
              <input type="text"  name="mes" id="mes" class="form-control" value="{{old('mes')}}" placeholder="Mes...">
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row"> 
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Concepto de Cobro</label>
                                <select name="pidConcepto" class="form-control selectpicker" id="pidConcepto" data-live-search="true">
                                      <option>Selecciona</option>
                                      @foreach($plan as $plan)
                                      <option value="{{$plan->idConceptosPagos}}_{{$plan->precio}}_{{$plan->impuesto}}">{{$plan->codigoConcepto}}</option>
                                      @endforeach
                                </select>
                          </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pprecio">Precio</label>
                                <input type="text" name="pprecio"  class="form-control" id="pprecio" disabled placeholder="Precio Venta...">
                          </div>
                    </div>
                   
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="impuesto">Impuesto</label>
                                <input type="text" name="pimpuesto" id="pimpuesto" class="form-control" disabled placeholder="Impuesto...">
                          </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                                 <label for="cantidad">Cantidad</label>
                                <input type="number" name="pcantidad" id="pcantidad" class="form-control" placeholder="Impuesto...">
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                                 <button id="bt_add" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Agregar</button>
                          </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="detalles">
                                <thead style="background-color:#A9D0F5">
                                    <th>Opciones</th>
                                    <th>Concepto</th>
                                    <th>Precio</th>
                                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                                    <th>Impuesto</th>
                                    <th>Subtotal</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <th>TOTAL</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>  
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th><h4 id="total">$/. 0.00</h4><input type="hidden" name="total_venta" id="total_venta"></th>
                                </tfoot>
                                 <tbody>
                                      
                                </tbody>
                          </table>
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>  
          <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="guardar">
            <div class="form-group">
                          <input value ="{{csrf_token() }}" name="_token" type="hidden">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Guardar</button>
              <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset">Cancelar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>   


  {!!Form::close()!!}   
        
</div>
```

Específicamente, cuando intento hacer esta operación:

```
 iva = precio * 16 / 100;
 subtotal[cont] = precio+iva;
 total=total+subtotal[cont];
```

y de igual manera cuando hago la validación para verificar si está vacío:

```
 if(consepto!=" " &&  precio!=" " && impuesto!=" " && cantidad!= " ")
```

La validación no pasa y me crea la fila y la operación en lugar de sumar los datos de las variables solo los concatena. ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: Intentalo asi `subtotal[cont] = parseInt(precio)+iva;`

Comment: diferentes formas de "pasar cadenas a números" y los tiempos de cada uno: http://jsben.ch/zGJHM

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para entender mejor, vamos por algo de código:

```
var bar = true;
console.log(bar + 0);   
console.log(bar + "xyz");  
console.log(bar + true);  
console.log(bar + false);
```

Esto da como resultado:

```
1
"truexyz"
2
1
```

JavaScript es un lenguaje muy "particular", por no decir algo raro para desarrolladores que venimos desde una perspectiva "tipada".

Aquí tienes una regla de oro para entender cómo es que funciona la adición o concatenación en JavaScript cuando se hace uso del operador "+":

```
Number  + Number  -> Addition
Boolean + Number  -> Addition
Boolean + Number  -> Addition
Number  + String  -> Concatenation
String  + Boolean -> Concatenation
String  + String  -> Concatenation
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está acá:

```
precio=$("#pprecio").val();
```

El precio te lo está tomando como un String !! Parsealo antes de guardarlo o aplicarle operaciones aritmeticas